# How do I run a specific single test in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've searched throughout the net but can't seem to find a solution to this and the following example is not working:

```
# spec/my_spec.rb
describe myText do
  it "won't work" do
    raise "never reached"
  end

  it "will work", :focus => true do
    1.should = 1
  end
end

$ rspec --tag focus spec/my_spec.rb
```

any help guys?

Answer (score 5):

In general, to execute a single spec, you can just do

```
rspec path/to/your/spec.rb:123
```

where `123` is the number of the line that your spec starts at.

However, your specific example can never work because you have two typos:

```
1.should = 1
```

should be

```
1.should eq 1      # deprecated to use 'should'
```

because otherwise you're assigning "1" to "1.should", which doesn't make sense.

You also can't write "describe myText", because myText is not defined anywhere. You probably meant `describe 'myText'`.

Finally, the preferred approach for RSpec assertions is

```
expect(1).to eq 1  # preferred
```

To prove this works, I did:

```
mkdir /tmp/example
gem_home .
gem install rspec

cat spec.rb
# spec.rb
describe "example" do
  it "won't work" do
    raise "never reached"
  end

  it "will work", :focus => true do
    expect(1).to eq 1
  end
end
```

and this passes, executing only the "will work" spec:

```
rspec --tag focus spec.rb
Run options: include {:focus=>true}
.

Finished in 0.0005 seconds (files took 0.05979 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Why did you set  {"focus->true}
Can you please add me on skype: simonansong

Comment: That's just the RSpec output -- only the first line in that block, `rspec --tag focus spec.rb` is the actual command.